# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in file.php

Tags: php, concatenation

I have this code:

```
$numPage = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < $numPage; $i++) {
 echo "Current Page: ".$i+1."/$numPage<br>";

}
```

why I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' on line 4
```

I concatenate correctly outside of the string, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add parantheses: `echo "Current Page: ".($i+1)."/$numPage<br>";`

Answer (score 3):

Special case. The *tokenizer* expected a float constant here:

```
 +1."
```

This is not seen as a one and the concatenation dot, but as the leading 1. of a 1.003 for example.
 Note that you don't need any whitespace or extra parens if you wrote:

```
 echo "Current Page: ".$i+1.0."/$numPage<br>";
```

The error message is a little misleading.

---

Note, that this just avoids the parsing error. This might still lead to an invalid result.

Comment: You still need the parenthesis ;) But still +1 for noticing that this is actually a lexing issue ;)

Comment: @NikiC You *don't* need parenthesis (to get it to parse -- "working" is another story). A space before the `.` would "fix" the syntax error as well. +1 for the explanation of *why* it is a syntax error: moral of the story: write readable code -- it matters to the computer as well ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`+` and `.` have the same operator precedence and are left associative in PHP, so PHP interprets it as:

```
echo (("Current Page: ".$i)+1)."/$numPage<br>";
```

What you want is:

```
echo "Current Page: ".($i+1)."/$numPage<br>";
```

Or:

```
echo "Current Page: ", $i+1, "/$numPage<br>";
```

Comment: +1 For explaining the precedence. However, this *does not* explain the syntax error -- the fixed code just happens to bypass the issue. This contains no syntax error: `echo "Current Page: " . $i+1 . "/$numPage<br>";` even if it will fail to "work" as expected ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check "1." it may be treating it as a float. Use ($i+1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Spacing out the concatenation seems to work.

```
<?php
$numPage = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < $numPage; $i++) {
 echo "Current Page: " . $i+1 . "/$numPage<br>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like that:

```
$numPage = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < $numPage; $i++)
{
    echo "Current Page : " . ($i + 1) . " " . $numPage . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "Current Page: ".($i+1)."/$numPage<br>";
```

Order of operations doesn't apply just to math, but programming as well. Your code was saying:

1. append `$i` to the string
2. then add 1, converting the string to an integer (0) and resulting in integer (1)
3. then you were attempting to concatenate a string to an integer (1)